# Check login for Admin (hashmap)

Tags: java, authentication, hashmap

Im getting a null pointer exception on my login screen when looking for an admin. It works when I login as a user, but fails when an admin.

this is the block of code that checks the user and pass. Everything is stored as a HashMap. Also the admin is set on the start of the program.

```
if(RememberUserLogins.userMap.containsKey(getUser())){
      String storedPassword = RememberUserLogins.userMap.get(model.getUserName()); 

       if(storedPassword.equals(pname)){

         if(uname.equals("admin") && pname.equals("pass")){

           System.out.println("You are an admin....\n" + 
                              "....Launching admin page.");   
         }else{            

           System.out.println("Login Scussfull!!!");
           MainScreen view = new MainScreen(stage);            
         }            
       } else {

         System.out.println("Password incorrect");
       }
     } else {

      System.out.println("User not Registered, "
          + "Please Register now.");
    }
```

Comment: uname and pname are equal to the values entered in the text feilds (this is a gui)

Comment: also the error im getting is a NPE

Comment: Which line is causing the npe?

Comment: if(storedPassword.equals(pname))

Comment: Storepassword is null. How are you putting values into that map?

Comment: String storedPassword = RememberUserLogins.userMap.get(model.getUserName()); 

its in the block i have here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contains check is checking against whatever object the "getUser()" returns. But then you try extracting pwd by using username as the key.

Try get password by

```
userMap.get(getUser());
```

Comment: That was it. Stupid mistake on my part. Thank you!